# ExtJS PUT request to Tomcat server is not allowed

Tags: rest, http, tomcat, extjs

I implemented a grid with records and a form in order to create and update these records. When editing a record and saving it afterwards, the client will go through the following lines:

```
var form = this.getView().getForm();
var record = form.getRecord();
record.beginEdit();
var updatedRecord = form.getValues();
record.set(updatedRecord);
record.endEdit();
```

By doing that, the client will send a PUT request to the Tomcat server with the updated parameters inside the body.

The tomcat server allows all HTTP messages as set in the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I use a browser plugin in order to send HTTP requests, everything is fine as we can see in this response:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Allow: PUT
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 190
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 22 May 2017 12:21:40 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

But when ExtJS sends the PUT request, I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1337
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Allow: DELETE,GET,OPTIONS
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1056
Date: Mon, 22 May 2017 11:55:37 GMT
```

Why does tomcat not allow PUT, GET and POST, if ExtJS sends a PUT request.
When ExtJS sends a POST request, everything works fine and I get the following response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:1337
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Content-Length:225
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 22 May 2017 12:59:07 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

What do I have to do to get Tomcat to allow PUT messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `headers` in `proxy` config of store in EXTJS.

```
proxy: {
    headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" }
    ...
}
```

I think by specifying headers your problem should resolve.

I thinks `actionMethod` also can create issue.

By default `extjs's store` sends `GET` request but if you want it to send `PUT` request then you can specify in `actionMethods` config

```
proxy: {
    actionMethods: {
            read : 'PUT',
            create : 'POST', 
            update : 'PUT', 
            destroy : 'DELETE'
        }
...
}
```

Please refer [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.html#method-getActionMethods).

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: Have you put all headers that server is expecting? or can you show me you back end request code?have you checked your MediaType?

Comment: Please refer my latest edited answer. hope this helps.

Comment: I accept all HTTP methods in my tomcat. The actionMethods thing isn't the problem since the client does create a PUT message when updating.